# Should we be more clear about using Mathematica.SE for Mathematica questions?

Tags: discussion

The [wolfram-mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-mathematica) tag excerpt says:

> Wolfram Mathematica is a computer algebra system and programming
>   language from Wolfram Research. Mathematica has its own Stack Exchange
>   site at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Most of the questions posted on Stack Overflow are closed as off-topic and migrated over to [mathematica.stackexchange.com](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com). I totally understand that we need to keep the old Mathematica answers in here, but nowadays the community seems to be just on that site. I don't think this is the same case as [this other thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322009/stack-overflow-vs-database-administrators) for example. In that case, the community is more divided, and active on both sites while with Mathematica, all activity happens on Mathematica.SE.

So firstly, should we just encourage everyone to avoid questions of this software on Stack Overflow and directly go to the other Stack Exchange website?

If so, should we modify the tag description so it is more clear about this? Something in the lines of:

> Wolfram Mathematica is a computer algebra system and programming
>   language from Wolfram Research. Please post all questions about Mathematica in its own Stack Exchange
>   site at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I suppose the underlying question would be, is there anyone out there that is asking programming-specific questions to Mathematica on here more than they are on Mathematica.SE?

Comment: I've seen some @Makoto. This question came up because I ended up in a new, mathematica specific question in SO. There are not a lot of them, but  there still are

Comment: "I totally understand that we need to keep the old Mathematica answers in here" - Hm, to me this is not obvious. Is there any special reason apart from on-topic/off-topic why we need to keep them?

Comment: @Trilarion no, not actually. I am personally OK with just putting everything on the Mathematica.SE site

Comment: @Trilarion it's SE policy to not migrate questions older than 60 days ([discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)). When Mathematica.SE was created some older questions were migrated by request nonetheless. -- I'm also a fan of organization and moving everything over though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even without closed and migrated questions there are still quite a few recent [non-closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-mathematica?sort=newest&pageSize=50) in that tag. Mostly, they score very low (often zero) and not all of them have answers (although some do).

The rule for questions that are on-topic in several StackExchanges is that the questioner chooses one and that's it. So if a questioner insists on having an on-topic question about programming in Mathematica here, it shall be here and the request to post all questions about Mathematica somewhere else would be wrong.

Since the on-topic questions about Mathematica also have a home here and the StackOverflow community is big and many members of it also know about Mathematica, we would probably just recommend the dedicated Mathematica StackExchange. And that is what is already in the existing tag wiki. It's mentioned prominently already.

If you are concerned about questioners making a disadvantageous choice, I would like to add that I don't think many people read tag wikis before posting questions. Much more important is commenting on unanswered questions here and explaining that this question has much higher chances on getting answered on Mathematica.SE.

People often have more than one question about a topic and once they tried the other StackExchange, they will use them according to their experiences.

Synopsis: The tag wiki is okay. Questions about programming Mathematica are on-topic here and some get answered. Commenting on unanswered questions and making advertisement for Mathematica.SE is the best thing to do.